# Footer with background and image with transparency showing body background instead of footer background

Tags: html, css

So I have an interesting design element that is proving to be a pain to get to look right with some HTML and CSS. I have an image in my footer that is transparent and should show the body background, but the footer also has a background image. It should look like this:

My initial thought was to use negative margins like this:
[image: Footer]

The problem is that the partners image is getting the background image of the left and right divs even with the margins. It ends up looking like this instead:
[image: Broken Footer]

CSS:

```
.footer-partners { width: 100%; }
.footer-partners-left,
.footer-partners-mid,
.footer-partners-right { float: left; height: 122px; }
.footer-partners-left,
.footer-partners-right { background: url('../img/partners-bg.png'); }
.footer-partners-left { width: 50%; margin-right: -83px; }
.footer-partners-mid { width: 164px; background: url('../img/partners.png') no-repeat; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -99999px; }
.footer-partners-right { width: 50%; margin-left: -81px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-partners clearfix">
    <div class="footer-partners-left"></div>
    <div class="footer-partners-mid"></div>
    <div class="footer-partners-right"></div>
</div>
```

My thought was that backgrounds don't display on margins, so the negative margin should make room for the transparent image and also not display the background there. Unfortunately the backgrounds are still showing on the margins. The only reason this is an issue is the footer background needs to go across 100% of the width of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the following changes to the CSS. All that was needed to do was to switch the negative margins to the outside of the page, instead of the center.

```
.footer-partners { width: 100%; }
.footer-partners-left,
.footer-partners-mid,
.footer-partners-right { float: left; height: 122px; }
.footer-partners-left,
.footer-partners-right { width: 50%; background: url('../img/partners-bg.png'); }
.footer-partners-left { margin-left: -83px; }
.footer-partners-mid { width: 164px; background: url('../img/partners.png') no-repeat; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -99999px; }
.footer-partners-right { margin-right: -81px; }
```